# Create a dynamic drop down menu in MS excel with database driven data

Tags: php, mysql, excel, web-applications

I would like to create a dynamic drop down menu in excel. I am using two sheets, sheet1 having the drop down menus and sheet2 having the reference data. I already did what other excel tutorials said by using a named range and INDIRECT to create a dynamic drop down, but, this is manually done. My data at sheet2 will be coming from mySQL database so the data will vary from time to time and the named reference will be inconsistent. Is it possible to automate this? Can I create a dynamic drop down? By the way, I am using PHP as my server side script which I use to populate my sheet2 with data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In excel go to the data tab select from other sources: select the connection you want to use. in the properties window, define the table or query which will provide the source data for the dropdown.  have the data "refresh" when the sheet opens.  The only issue will be saving the password/userid to connect to the dtabase as it is in clear text and anyone can access.

Comment: yes, that could also work, however, how about the dynamic drop down? How to go about this?

Comment: use named ranges that extend that extend the entire column, or 50-100 rows.  I believe ( dont' know) that excel will drop the duplicate/empty rows.  so what would happen is that excel opens, refreshes data; and then dropdowns have updated values.

Comment: yes. It does update the excel file. But the problem here is the mapping of dynamic drop down so they'll know what to show next.